# C++ Destructor being called when variable still alive

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a class with a pointer to an integer.

Then a static function that will return the value of that integer.

I'm noticing when calling the static function the destructor is called for that object everytime.

I don't understand why this behavior is happening.

```
class Dog
{
public:

Dog(int val){
 this->pVal = new int(val);
}

~Dog(){
 delete this->pVal;
}

static int GetVal(Dog d){
  return *(d.pVal);
}

int *pVal;
};
```

That is the class.

Here is my test driver code.

```
Dog fido(20);
std::cout << Dog::GetVal(fido);  //20 and destructor for fido called
Dog rex(21);
std::cout << Dog::GetVal(fido); //21 but should be 20 
std::cout << Dog::GetVal(rex);   // should be 21
```

I'm noticing that both dog objects live at different memory addresses but the int pointer lives at the same address.  I believe this is because fido's destructor is called when calling GetVal but I don't know why that behavior is occuring.

Comment: If you had used unique_ptr instead of managing the lifetime by hand, your compiler had shown you your error (the code would not compile).

Comment: Just because the answer to another question applies to this one doesn't make this question a duplicate.  This question is posed by demonstrating a problem; the "duplicate" asks about a specific topic.  You would not know that the so-called duplicate is relevant unless you already knew what the problem with this question's code is.

Comment: I agree with Darryl’s comment above. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although the destructor for "Fido" is indeed being called, this is not the original "Fido", but its copy. Your `GetVal(Dog d)` function takes `Dog` by value, which means that "Fido" is copied before being passed to `GetVal`, and then the copy is destroyed upon completion.

Passing `Dog&` by `const` reference fixes this problem:

```
static int GetVal(const Dog& d){
    return *(d.pVal);
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/NUPTRa)

**Note:** The above does not explain why you get 21 for "Fido". Since you did not define a copy constructor or an assignment operator, the compiler generated a trivial copy constructor for you. As the result, `pVal` in "Fido"'s copy is pointing to the same location as `pVal` in the original "Fido". As soon as the copy gets destroyed upon return from `Dog::GetVal(fido)` the memory becomes eligible for reuse, and the pointer inside the original "Fido" becomes dangling. When you call `Dog::GetVal(fido)` for the second time, the function causes undefined behavior by dereferencing a dangling pointer. The fact that the second call prints 21, the value that you passed to "Rex"'s constructor, strongly suggests that the memory freed up on destroying "Fido"'s copy is being reused immediately in constructing "Rex". However, there is no requirement for C++ to do that. If this happens, your code causes UB for the second time when "Rex" and "Fido" are destroyed at the end of the run.

Comment: Ah thank you so much. I didn't realize a copy was created.

Comment: @mocode10 There are some rules which you should follow to prevent problems like this. Specifically, the rule of five or rule of zero: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-five, https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-zero

Comment: Another approach to solve this was to overload the copy constructor to create a new int pointer as well.